# Unable to switch from Minikube to AWS EKS on windows for Deployment

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, amazon-eks, minikube

I have minikube on my local machine for testing deployment and I ran commands like

```
kubectl apply -f testingfile.yaml
```

and it worked fine. Now I want to perform the same on aws eks. I have followed all steps given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sample-deployment.html. Created a config file and added that to the path. Commands like `eksctl get cluster` are correctly listing the clusters from aws eks but now when I run

```
kubectl apply -f testingfile.yaml
```

I am getting the following statement
`deployment.apps/testingfile unchanged` which means it is still applying the command inside minikube and not on aws eks. I have also deleted path variables related to minikube from environment variables but I am still unable to switch to aws eks for applying. I would like to deploy this on aws eks. Let me know what I am missing here

Answer (score 2):

Checking your existing cluster contexts

There will multiple contexts one for Minikube and One for EKS

```
kubectl config get-contexs
```

change context to EKS if your config is set it will be there

```
kubectl config use-context <Name of context>
```

this way you can get changed to another clusters.